# what types of image processing i need to make image clear for OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv, ocr

i'm working on android application to capture image and detect page number using OCR, I made some processing using OpenCv on image and now i'am stuck at this point  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1I8u.png)![See the image]

So what the next step to get new image which will contains only numbers for OCR??

Comment: it depends. Is always in that position? There is always the same pattern? etc.. If it's only for this image it would be pretty easy...

Comment: yes always the same position ,@Miki how can i do it ??

Comment: use a roi.. :D I'll upload the code

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes  this is the result i want to get , but  the coordination of ROI will be a Little different  from image to image , it will depend on how the user will capture the image. by the way thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the numbers are always in the same position, the easiest way to select them would be to select that portion of image, like this:

```
Mat1b gray = imread("pat_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Rect roi(285, 630, 130, 100);   // Manually selected values
Mat1b numbers = gray(roi).clone();
```

numbers would be like this:

[image]